# TR1 is "missing" - which header or library am I missing from my project configuration?

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to use some types from TR1/functional. I have the following reference in my header file:

```
#include <tr1/functional>
```

This is resulting in an error:

> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/functional': No such file or
>   directory.

This has always worked before. I've been browsing MSDN trying to determine if I'm missing a library reference or something of the sort, but for the life of me I'm unable to find out what is wrong with my project configuration.

I'm using C++11 and working in Visual Studio 2013 Developer Preview.

Comment: If you're using C++11, just `#include <functional>`. TR1 was more like a preview.

Comment: `tr1` should have been for older compilers like VS2010. As I recall though, although everything was moved out of the `std::tr1` namespace, `std::regex` remains stuck in `std::tr1::regex`.

Comment: @chris, Rapptz, thanks that was it. I'm new to C++11. If one of you would make a normal answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Rapptz - an implementation of TR1 puts all of its stuff into the nested namespace `std::tr1`. C++11 does not have that nested namespace; everything that was added to the standard library is in the namespace `std`, including all the regular expression code. Existing code that uses TR1 should continue to work, unless the implementation of TR1 has been removed. But C++11 says nothing about TR1; in particular, it does not require that it be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<tr1/*>` headers should have been deprecated or removed following their inclusion in the standard. So they're mostly there for older compilers such as VS2010 or VS2008. Including `<functional>` alone should fix it.

A couple things to note though, although I do not know if it applies to VS2013 is that `std::regex`'s include is `<regex>` yet still resides in the old `std::tr1` namespace.

Comment: I just checked VS2013. `std::regex` works fine (i.e., compiles and correctly matches "abc" with "...").

Comment: The TR1 headers have **not** been deprecated. TR1 is independent of C++11. Most of what was in TR1 has been added to C++11, and the committee recently decided to let TR1 lapse. That doesn't preclude vendors from continuing to ship TR1.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using VS 2013 and faced same problem. After few research, finaly I got it working using Boost. It is prety well supported.